# What does it mean when the mean of a sample close to the standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

I have did a MCMC and get a sample for parameter A in a model. Then the mean of the sample is close to the standard deviation, for example, mean $\mu = 0.01$, standard deviation std = 0.01, then what does it mean. My tutor told me it showed the estimation for A was insignificant, which indicates parameter A is not necessary in the model. But I am confused about it, could anyone show more comments on it?

Thanks

Comment: If the standard deviation is almost 0, it means your sample is almost constant. On the other hand standard deviation is invariant to translation but mean isn't...

Comment: Can the measured value be negative? if not, then a standard deviation close to the mean indicates that your distribution is not Normal. Another distribution (eg. Rayleigh) might be appropriate.

Comment: @Joffan Thanks. Actually, I am going to discuss whether the parameter A is necessary in the model. My tutor told me it was a common principle in statistics but I do not know.

Comment: @LeonhardtvonM Thanks Leonhardt, I can understand if the standard deviation is almost a constant but does anything indicates if the estimated mean and std are in the same decimal?

Comment: Let $X$ a random variable with the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$ then the standard deviation and mean of $X-\mu+\sigma$ are the same. This fact shows, that the equality of the mean and standard deviation cannot indicates too much.